# Grep multiple line between curly braces using shell command

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to grep multiple lines between curly braces from a file . An example of the file originalfile.txt could be:

```
{
"User ID": "admin",
"Tower Job ID": "",
"Date": "Fri Jan 15 12:50:13 UTC 2021",
"Playbook Input": [
  {"Host FQDN": "abc.cloud"},
  {"Host IP Address": "10.10.10.1"},
  {"Host Serial Number": "ABCD"},
  {"RITM Ticket": "sk_123"}
 ],
"Playbook Output": {
 "Results" : [

 { "Update server" : "Pass" , "Result" : "done" },
 { "Decom server" : "Pass" , "Result" : "done" },
 { "Check process" : "Pass" , "Result" : "done" },
 { "Schedule" : "Pass" , "Result" : "Scheduled @ 2021-01-15 04:53:55" },
 { "Playbook summary" : "Pass" , "Result" : "Complete" }
 ]
}
}
```

I want to grep only lines after `Playbook Output` like:

```
{
 "Results" : [

 { "Update server" : "Pass" , "Result" : "done" },
 { "Decom server" : "Pass" , "Result" : "done" },
 { "Check process" : "Pass" , "Result" : "done" },
 { "Schedule" : "Pass" , "Result" : "Scheduled @ 2021-01-15 04:53:55" },
 { "Playbook summary" : "Pass" , "Result" : "Complete" }
 ]
}
```

Is there a way to grep specific content between curly braces from a file.s

Comment: Can you use `jq`? `grep` is not the right tool for searching JSON

Comment: initially started with JQ, but due to security reason, installing jq was not allowed so cant able use jq

Comment: The name `playbook` suggest ansible. Why not `python`? I believe there are awk and bash parsers on github, but honestly the simplest way is to install `jq`.

Comment: yes,  originalfile.txt generated by ansible playbook

Comment: Then use python, you have it installed.

Comment: @satheeshkumar : In your case, the `{ ... }` part is **nested**, and you can normally not parse a nested construct by using a regular expression (unless you have a regexp engine which supports this explicitly) in general. It may work out in very special cases, but you gave here just an _example_ for your file and not a general description of how (and at which places) in the file the data you are looking for, exists. Hence, I recommend to stay away from regexp in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n -e '/Results/,$p' yourfile.dat
```

If you want to preserve the brace on top:

```
sed -n -e '/Results/,$p' yourfile.dat | sed -e '1 i {'
```

Output:

```
{
 "Results" : [

 { "Update server" : "Pass" , "Result" : "done" },
 { "Decom server" : "Pass" , "Result" : "done" },
 { "Check process" : "Pass" , "Result" : "done" },
 { "Schedule" : "Pass" , "Result" : "Scheduled @ 2021-01-15 04:53:55" },
 { "Playbook summary" : "Pass" , "Result" : "Complete" }
 ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your input is structed as JSON so you can use the jq shell tool to filter it

```
$ jq '."Playbook Output"' foo.json
{
  "Results": [
    {
      "Update server": "Pass",
      "Result": "done"
    },
    {
      "Decom server": "Pass",
      "Result": "done"
    },
    {
      "Check process": "Pass",
      "Result": "done"
    },
    {
      "Schedule": "Pass",
      "Result": "Scheduled @ 2021-01-15 04:53:55"
    },
    {
      "Playbook summary": "Pass",
      "Result": "Complete"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, initially started with JQ but as per the policy i cant install in prod/uat environments.

Comment: An alternative might be to use a python or go (or whatever language X) to write a simple converter that can load json